# What making new object is running this method , though it is not a constructor?

Tags: java, email

```
package com.robin;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.util.Properties;
public class main{
    private static final String SMTP_HOST_NAME = "";
    private static final String SMTP_AUTH_USER = "";
    private static final String SMTP_AUTH_PWD  = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        new main().test();
    }

    public void test() throws Exception{
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_HOST_NAME);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "2525");

        Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, auth);
        // uncomment for debugging infos to stdout
        // mailSession.setDebug(true);
        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        message.setContent("This is a test", "text/plain");
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(""));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(""));

        transport.connect();
        transport.sendMessage(message,
                message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        transport.close();
    }

    private class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            String username = SMTP_AUTH_USER;
            String password = SMTP_AUTH_PWD;
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    }
}
```

What making new object(`Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();`) is running  `getPasswordAuthentication()` method , though it is not a constructor?

Normally if we create an object it's constructor runs, but this method is not a constructor.
I am really confused by this code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your question

Comment: As best I can tell, you are confusing static vs. non-static methods.  `main` is the name of the class, so `new main()` creates a new `main` object so that you can call the non-static, member method `test`.  It seems to me that `test()` should be a static method so that you call it as either just `test()` or `main.test()`...also you're not following the naming convention that a class is upper camel case.  `main` looks like a variable (lower camel case), but it actually a class.

Comment: Ok,I will follow this from now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is constructor chaining.**

Constructor chaining occurs through the use of inheritance. A subclass constructor method's first task is to call its superclass' constructor method.

First the constructor of base class will run and then only the constructor of the child class or deriving class will run.

As you have extended class `javax.mail.Authenticator` , the constructor gets called automatically

Comment: I just have practiced what you said, Now I have got it.

The code I have written: http://pastebin.com/YEmvWSJZ

Comment: I have learned that , creating new objects calls it super-class's constructor. and this constructor is calling the getPasswordAuthentication() method which is overridden by new class

Comment: @user2536419, actually, this does not answer your question: what fires the getPasswordAuthentication() method!

Comment: @Rami.Q Actually it does, because he needs to override the method else it will return null as you said. And this happens only because of the reason that I have mentioned in my answer. Please read the answer carefully and only comment

Answer (score 0):

from the JavaDocs of the javax.mail.Authenticator

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/mail/Authenticator.html#getPasswordAuthentication%28%29

> Called when password authentication is needed. Subclasses should
>   override the default implementation, which returns null.

When the provider needs to know a username or password, it calls back to the getPasswordAuthentication() method in your **SMTPAuthenticator** subclass of **Authenticator**. This returns a PasswordAuthentication object:

```
@Override
protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){....}
```

Comment: @user2536419 glad that i could help